# GCC with XScale and ARMv5TE

Tags: gcc, arm, xscale

Why am I getting the following gcc (4.6.1) warning?

```
warning: switch -mcpu=xscale conflicts with -march=armv5te switch
[enabled by default]
```

The "Intel XScale Core Developer's Manual" states:

> The Intel XScale® core implements the integer instruction set architecture specified in ARM V5TE.

EDIT: The GCC manual states the following about the `-march=` option:

```
This option can be used in conjunction with or instead of the -mcpu= option.
```

So these two switches *can* be used together. The problem lies therefore in the values (xscale and amrv5te). So *why* such a conflict between these two values?

Comment: I'm not sure, but, is there an march options for xscale instead?

Answer (score 3):

In GCC there's a set of flags, describing the each supported ISA architecture and each supported implementation (core). GCC does a basic consistency check between `-mcpu` and `-march` options to verify that the set of flags are the same (except the flags, which affect only tuning and not ISA).

Do not use `-mcpu`, use `-march=armv5te -mtune=xscale`.

Comment: I know of the consistency checks... Why is my combination inconsistent? The XScale _is_ ARMv5TE...